# Update List<T> through self join?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, generics

First off I am very new to LINQ.

I have a list which has data something like this :

**list**

```
 list[0] = id=1,block=10,sg=320,dc=null

 list[1] = id=1,block=10,sg=null,dc=320

 list[2] = id=2,block=15,sg=400,dc=null

 list[3] = id=2,block=15,sg=null,dc=400
```

**I want to update this list such that :**

```
if(sg where block=x  and id=y  is null) 
then set sg = (sg where block=x  and id=y  is not null) 
and similarly for dc
```

**Desired Result:**

```
 list[0] = id=1,block=10,sg=320,dc=320 

 list[1] = id=2,block=15,sg=400,dc=400
```

NOTE: id and block are identifying factors here.

**CLASS:**

```
public  class dcsg
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> dcvalue { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> sgvalue { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> revision { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> timestampid { get; set; }
        public decimal fuelcost { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> isdeleted { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> blockno { get; set; }
        public int stageid { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Stuck anywhere in particular? Also your result is not what you described before - the "desired result" has null entries removed, while description suggests you want to keep them, and copy over the missing info

Comment: It would be useful if you show the T class

Comment: Would the result contain only two items or all the items?

Comment: @Andrei NULL is the missing value! For each unique combination of block and id there should always be one resultant row. Right now there are two for each unique combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this using `Linq`, `GroupBy`.

```
lists = lists.GroupBy(x=> new {x.id, x.blockno})
             .Select(x=> 
              {
                 var sg1 = x.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.sgvalue.HasValue);
                 var dc1 = x.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.dcvalue.HasValue);  
                 return new dcsg() // create class instance if have one.
                 {
                     id= x.Key.id,
                     blockno= x.Key.blockno,
                     sgvalue = sg1==null? null; sg1.sgvalue, 
                     dcvalue = dc1==null? null; dc1.dcvalue,
                     // copy other properties (if needed). 
                 };
              })
             .ToList();
```

Obviously, code snippet written with two assumptions.

1. In case of multiple `sg` appear for same block *first* sg will betaken (but this can be changed based on need).
2. Based on your example, `id,block` are used to group list items.

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not seem to change the list. Values are as it is even after passing through it.

Comment: It creates new `List`, so assign it back to same list.

Comment: @Arbaaz, Q in LINQ stands for "query". Linq does not change lists, it is designed to query them and create new lists

Comment: Error at `blockno= x.Key.blockno,`

  'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'blockno' and no extension method 'blockno' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: ahh..I was taken `blockno` value instead of nullable property itslef, try now. @Arbaaz